# Java Calendar behave differently

Tags: java, android, calendar, dayofweek

In the following snippet of code, I try to get the date of first day of current week, in a week system that starts from Saturday:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SATURDAY);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

when I run this code [here](http://ideone.com/f3VWHn), the computed date is correctly previous Saturday (today is Tuesday by the way), but when I use this code in my Android program, date is set to next Saturday! Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try Calendar with the timezone or locale arguments. That way you should be able to make sure there isn't a different value for different locales / timezone.

Like this:

```
Calendar.getInstance(Locale.CANADA);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but Locale doesn't have the value I want. Plus, I wanna know what's going on! The point is that in both platforms, `setFirstDayOfWeek()` works, and set the first day of week to Saturday. now that we are in a week that has been started in previous Saturday, why `cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SATURDAY);` would set date to next Saturday?!

Comment: And I should say that, setting timezone introduced a new behavior! I think it caused date to be set to Sunday, despite of the fact that I said the first day of week is Friday!